# Nested jquery accordion is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to create a nested jquery accordion but the output isnt correct. 
I have created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/p3Dnp/

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
$(function() {
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: false });
});
$('div.accordion').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>11</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>12</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>21</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>22</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>3</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>31</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>32</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see when I add a nested accordion it just eats up the parent accordion headers
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You use `$('div.accordion')` ; But there is no `div` with a accordion class there. And you have given all the `div`s the same `id`. bad html.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I tried using class instead of id still no change

Comment: I didn't say it would work. I said it's bad to give the same id to multiple elements. Change the code to use classes, and then paste the new code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML has incorrect closing div s and id cant be repeated for the section, we must use class attribute for nested accordion
Your markup should like this,

```
<div class="accordion">
        <h3>1</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>11</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>12</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
        <h3>2</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>21</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>22</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>3</h3>
        <div>
            <p>                 
            </p>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>31</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion">
                <h3>32</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>                 
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One accordion call is enough for us

```
$('div.accordion').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
```

I updated the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Dnp/6/) . I think this is what u expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use unique [header attribute selectors](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header) for nested accordions, as per the documentation,

> Selector for the header element, applied via .find() on the main accordion element. Content panels must be the sibling immediately after their associated headers.

this means that if you do not define a unique selector (the default being `h3`) it will bind click events to all .find('h3') elements and therefore inner accordions will also trigger the outer ones.

Hence, do something like

```
$('#accordion').accordion(
  autoHeight: false,
  collapsible: true,
  active: false,
  header: '> h3'
});
```

this ensures that only the direct `h3` children are used as headers.